# Converting a nested SCNNode position to a CGPoint in screen space

Tags: ios, 3d, scenekit, scnnode

I'm trying to convert the 3d position of a nested SCNNode in to an x, y (CGPoint) coordinate (for overlaying a view over the object).

My SCNNode structure looks like:

```
      +-----------+
      | Root node |
      +-----+-----+
            |
            |
       +----+---+
    +--+ Node A +--+
    |  +--------+  |
    |              |
    |              |
    |              |
+---+----+    +----+---+
| Node B |    | Node C |
+--------+    +--------+
```

I'd like to get the screen space 2d position of NodeB. I'm aware of the [convertPosition:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNNode_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SCNNode/convertPosition:fromNode:) and [projectPoint:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNSceneRenderer_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/SCNSceneRenderer/projectPoint:) methods but I don't think I'm using them correctly.

Any pointers?

Edit:

Currently trying something like this:

```
SCNVector3 rootPosition = [[[[self view3D] scene] rootNode] convertPosition:[nodeB position] fromNode:nodeB];
SCNVector3 projectedPoint = [[self view3D] projectPoint:rootPosition];
NSLog(@"x %f y %f z %f", projectedPoint.x, projectedPoint.y, projectedPoint.z);
```

The resulting x, y, z are way off (and sometimes negative, which doesn't make sense in screen space as the object is plainly in view).

Comment: Can you post what you've got so far?

Comment: @wogsland Edited with code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NodeB's position is specified in terms of NodeA's coordinate system. So I believe you want

```
rootPosition = [rootNode convertPosition:nodeB.position fromNode:nodeA]
```

Answer (score 2):

On **swift4**:

```
nodeAchildPosition = scnScene.rootNode.convertPosition(nodeA.position, from: nodeAchild)
```

Comment: Is this answer getting the position of nodeB, or nodeA? (It seems reversed from Hal Mueller's answer!) And is there some (any?) reason you can't just use nodeB.parent for the `from` parameter?